# Doubt it minimum value open interval.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, terminology

The graph below is $f(x):$

[image]

Suppose there is a function: $f:\mathbb{R} \to (10,20]$ and someone asks us to find the minimum value $f$ can attain, then I was told the answer does not exist, because we can't say $10$ because it is not in its range. I get that it doesn't exist because there is no way to represent it. But what about the question below.

Consider another question worded like this.
$f:\mathbb{R} \to (10,20]$ and the minimum value of $f$ is $d$.
Then what is the correct option:

a) $0<d<5$

b) $5<d<15$

c) $15<d<20$

d) none of these

Is the answer b or d? and why? Since the minimum value is 10 plus an infinitesimally small value, isn't the answer option b?

Comment: There is a difference between the codomain of a function and its range. In this case, $(10,20]$ is the codomain which are the possible values of $f$. For example, $f(x)=15$ for all $x$ is perfectly valid.

Comment: ok then let me edit my question, that's not the doubt

Comment: @JohnDouma i editted the question by adding a picture of the graph. Please check it.

Comment: There is a difference between a minimum and an infimum. 10 is the infimum of $f$ because $10<f(x)$ for all $x$ and, as you correctly mention about infinitesimals, $f$ gets arbitrarily close to $10$. There is no minimum though, because there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=10$. If $f$ mapped to $[10,20]$, then the minimum would exist.

Comment: That function has no minimum. It is bounded below but since it takes on all values greater than $10$ we would have to be able to get the next value after $10$. Can you see why that is not possible?

Comment: yes @JohnDouma I see why that's not possible, because we cant say it is the next value after 10, but if we were asked what interval does it lie in, cant we say it is in this interval: [5,15]??

Comment: For part $2$, they must be talking about a different function. If so, all we can say is that it must be somewhere in the codomain. For example, $f(x)=20$ for all $x$ has a minimum value of $20$ which also happens to be its maximum value.

By the way, technically your drawing cannot be correct because $f$ is supposed to be defined on all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Do you want to change $f: \mathbb{R}\to(10,20]$ to $f: \Omega\to(10,20]$ for some $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Please see if these help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456967/why-does-a-global-extremum-on-an-open-interval-not-exist and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626235/why-does-fx-x-not-have-a-maximum-on-open-interval-0-1

Comment: thanks a lot guys... there is no minimum, it simply doesn't exist. We cant even specify a range for minimum cuz it simply does not exist.